# Why does my form validate when I fill in the very last input, even if all the others are empty?

Tags: javascript, forms, class, validation, oop

I have a contact form I'm trying to validate. I know you can just use the default 'required' attribute, however, I need to make the validation error messages custom. So, I have created this JS Class - When you initialise the class, you pass in the parameters e.g. the form you are targeting, the inputs within the form, and the submit button.

Here is a link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/Woodenchops/pen/oKxRGq?editors=1010

I've tried changing the if statement check from the 'this' keyword to the name of the fields '.field.required' - whenI did that, the first input would reactive the button, even if all others were empty

```
this._input = this._form.querySelectorAll(props.input);

this.checkFieldValue = function() {
     jQuery(this._input).each(function() {
       console.log(jQuery(this).val().length);
       if(jQuery(this).val().length <= 0) {
         $('.fake-click').show();
         var submitHeight = jQuery(submitButton).innerHeight();
         var submitWidth = jQuery(submitButton).innerWidth();
         var submitInputTop = jQuery(submitButton).position().top;
         var submitInputLeft = jQuery(submitButton).position().left;
         $('.fake-click').css({
           "background": "none",
           "width": submitWidth + 5,
           "height": submitHeight + 5,
           "position": "absolute",
           "top": submitInputTop,
           "left": submitInputLeft,
           "z-index": "1"
         });
         $(submitButton).css({
           "opacity": .5
         });
       } else {
         $('.fake-click').hide();
         $(submitButton).css({
           "opacity": 1
         });
       } 
     });
   }
```

There is quite a bit going on in this class. However, I'm trying to make it so that if any required fields are empty, the submit button will disable. I've used a jQuery each loop to loop through each input to check the value length. It KINDA works - you can start off with the first input, enter a value and work your way down to the last input - the submit button will stay disabled until you enter the last field. HOWEVER, if you simply go to the last input and enter a value, it will reactive the submit button - even if every other input is empty.

I'm then calling that function on a 'keyup' event on the inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop trough all the inputs and enable/disable the submit button after every iteration.
Only the last iteration (the last input) will determine the state of the submit button.

You can fix this by storing a boolean value if any of the inputs are invalid, and use that to determine if the submit button should be enabled. Like this:

```
this.checkFieldValue = function () {
    let isValid = true;
    jQuery(this._input).each(function () {
        console.log(jQuery(this).val().length);
        if (jQuery(this).val().length <= 0) {
            isValid = false;
        }
    });
    if (isValid === false) {
        $('.fake-click').show();
        var submitHeight = jQuery(submitButton).innerHeight();
        var submitWidth = jQuery(submitButton).innerWidth();
        var submitInputTop = jQuery(submitButton).position().top;
        var submitInputLeft = jQuery(submitButton).position().left;
        $('.fake-click').css({
            "background": "none",
            "width": submitWidth + 5,
            "height": submitHeight + 5,
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": submitInputTop,
            "left": submitInputLeft,
            "z-index": "1"
        });
        $(submitButton).css({
            "opacity": .5
        });
    } else {
        $('.fake-click').hide();
        $(submitButton).css({
            "opacity": 1
        });
    }
}
```